# Werewolf short story about a group of friends going skiing, with a plot twist at the end

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror, anthology-book, werewolf

I read this book in probably like 2015-2018 or so and I think it was in a kids' horror book compilation or something like that (not *Scary Stories to Tell in the Dark*). I also believe the cover might have had like one of those medieval men who execute people, like an executioner, pulling a carriage filled with body parts!

The only story I remember is one about werewolves. Basically, a group of kids go skiing and talk about this werewolf thing, where, when you are turning, you will get symptoms, like for example getting really warm and undressing and laying in the snow (like hyperthermia) and howling and stuff.

Eventually, one of the kids reacts to the Moon and runs off and the night continues and the other friend starts getting the hyperthermia-like symptoms and her friend tries helping her out but can't stop her from eventually running off and howling. The friend walks around looking for the girl but can't find her and eventually is attacked by a beast; a wolf. She stabs it with her ski pole and kills it and then runs back home.

The next day, a search party is sent out looking for the girl's friend (honestly, I don't know what happened with the boy who was first turned or what that was) and, after a while, they find the girl's friend dead, with a ski pole through her throat; the girl killed her best friend.

Comment: Hmm... is the story supposed to be implying that her friend was actually a werewolf, or that the girl who stabbed her was delusional herself?

Comment: It’s basically a small plot twist when you find out her friend actually did turn into a werewolf, she isn’t delusional she just didn’t recognize that it was her friend